# On weak star convergent sequences of functions that are not strongly convergent anywhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Can we find example of a sequence of functions $g_n:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ such that $g_n$ converges weak-star in ${\rm L}^{\infty}(0,1)$ as $n\rightarrow+\infty$, but such that for every measurable set $A\subseteq (0,1)$ such that $\lambda(A)>0$ the sequence $g_n\vert_{A}$ has no strongly convergent subsequence in ${\rm L}^{\infty}(A)$? In fact, I am dealing with a sequence of $\theta$-Holder continuous functions, for some fixed $0<\theta<1$ which is independent on $n$. Any chance of finding an example which satisfies all assumptions? Or maybe there is no such example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the Rademacher sequence? (or $f_n(t)=\sin nt$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark on previous comment by pozz: I point out that constant functions actualy have bounded oscillation property. In this previous comment we need to take into account that ${\rm sup}_{J^n_i}g_n\geq b$ is never satisfied, provided $g_n=c$, and provided we choose $b>c$. So there exists no sub-interval at all which satisfies both inf and sup estimate, as required in the definition of "bounded oscillation" property. Therefore, $g_n:=c$ is both strongly convergent and satisfies bounded oscillation property. The same argument applies to any sequence of functions which take values within some fixed discrete set (which is independent of $n$). Notice, however, that such sequences of "simple" functions are no longer continuous. Sorry for not answering the question, but maybe this observation helps.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't understand this definition of "bounded oscillation property", but it requires that "$\forall a,b,\,a<b$ there exists at most finitely many..."; so you can't choose $b>c$, one also has to check all the values $b\le c$, and for such values we have $\sup_J g_n\ge b$ for each subinterval $J$, that is an infinite family. Sorry if I missed something!

Comment: As I understand this definition, we need to satisfy both inf and sup condition. So, if we choose $a<c$ and, say, $b<c$, then inf condition is never satisfied (although sup condition IS satisfied). So in such a case there is no sub-intervals which satisfy both conditions. On the other hand, if we choose $a\leq c$ and  $b>c$, then sup condition is never satisfied. So in both cases we have BOP satisfied. Do we agree on that? If it helps, note that the only relevant choice of $a, b$ for a given $n$ are those which satisfy ${\rm inf}_{(0,1)}g_n\leq a$ and ${\rm sup}_{(0,1)}g_n\geq b$.

Comment: Oh yes I see, you're completely right! However I don't delete the comments so that the conversation makes sense.

Comment: Yes, and it is a very good coversation. But I still do not know if the BOP-upgraded assertion of delux is true or not. Any opinion?

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, the sequence $g_n(t)=\sin(nt)$ is a sequence in $L^\infty(0,1)$ that weak-star converges to $0$, each $g_n$ is also $\theta$-Holder continuous for every $\theta\in(0,1)$ since it is Lipschitz, but no subsequences of $g_n$ converge strongly on positive measure sets.

I just add a comment. The fact is that the functions $g_n$ are $\theta$-Holder continuous but with different (and unbounded) Holder norms, that is:

$$|g_n(t_1)-g_n(t_2)|\le C_n |t_1-t_2|^\theta$$

and $C_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

If we impose a bound on the constants $C_n$, that is we suppose $g_n$ are $\theta$-Holder with $C_n\le C$ for a $C$ indipendent of $n$, then now we have uniform convergence on $(0,1)$ of a subsequence by appliyng Ascoli-Arzelà Theorem (this is actually the so called compact embedding of Holder spaces in the space of continuous functions).

Comment: I thank you for your answers. I wonder if it helps if we add one additional condition on $g_n$, namely that for every $a,b\in\mathbf{R}$ such that $a<b$ there exists at most finitely many sub-intervals $(J^n_i)_{i=1}^{N_n}$ which satisfy ${\rm inf}_{J^n_i}g_n\leq a$ and ${\rm sup}_{J^n_i}g_n\geq b$, where $N_n=N_n(a,b)$ satisfies $N_n\leq N_0$ for some $N_0=N_0(a,b)\in\mathbf{N}$? This can be called the bounded oscillation property. I guess now rapidly oscillating functions can be excluded as a counterexample. Is it now true that we have strong convergence "somewhere" on $(0,1)$?

Comment: @delux I am not sure that the hypothesis about the "finitely many subintervals" is well posed; in the sense that: take for example a constant function $f=c$, it should have a "bounded oscillation property", but for $a\ge c$ we have $\inf_J f \le a$ for any $J$ subinterval of $(0,1)$, that is a non countable family of intervals (so there is not a finite family of subintervals such that the property holds). However I don't know what we can say with such assumptions!

Comment: @delux Update: my comment above is wrong, see below the answer of Andrija.